# An number theoretic inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Prove this inequality :
$$\displaystyle \prod_{i\le \left\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor{\frac{\left\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right\rfloor}{i}}\right\rfloor\le \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\cdots,n)$$
Induction doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Why do you want to prove this? Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: This is a practice problem I got. I was supposed to be submitting them last week. I didn't get this one, so I tried a lot to do it but couldn't so posted here. I was assured this was indeed true. Any and all help will be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I think a good approach would be to show that the lhs is less than, say, $\frac{1}{2}e^n$ (you might use Stirling's formula for the factorial part) while the rhs is greater than, say, $0.9e^n$ for $n$ greater than some bound (the prime number theorem implies $\log(\textrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n))/n$ is asymptotic to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity).